# what is the best way to create a separate swift file to handle functions i need to use throughout my application

Tags: ios, swift

I have some `ViewControllers` which are essentially templates that display data from an `API`. As I continue to develop each template is becoming more messy and I would like to clean it up and have the API Functions, Animations etc in separate files, so that I can make the Template `ViewControllers` much more organised.

I am new to any sort of coding and have done a course and trying to learn by doing.

here is the code of one of my templates, it takes cryptocurrency data from an api, and displays the data based on which coin the user selected, I have multiple of these templates so that the user can have a Coin for each page. Would it be better to create separate files to manage the animations, API data etc so that in the Templates i can just call them and make it much cleaner and if so what would be the best way to do so? Thank you.

```
//
//  Template2ViewController.swift
//  CryptoClockTesting
//
//  Created by Peter Ruppert on 18/07/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Peter Ruppert. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

var t2ViewController = Template2ViewController()

class Template2ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var searchView: UIView!

var nameReady = Int()
var chosenCoin: String = ""
var symbolReady = Int()


//random background generate number
let b = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
//choice appending the number of chosen coin from StartViewController
var choice = Int()
//Arrays for names and prices
var ids: [String] = []
var prices: [String] = []
var euros: [String] = []
var usd: [String] = []
var images: [String] = []
var names: [String] = []
//selection of random Background options
var backgroundArray = [ "Background0", "Background1", "Background2", "background3", "Background4", "Background5" ]
//labels and inputs
@IBOutlet weak var euroPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var usdPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var showConverter: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var newsView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var convertButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var textInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currencyPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var currencyIcon: UIImageView!

//Converting price from coin price to GBP
func convert() {
    let originalPrice = prices[choice]
    let priceAsDouble = Double(originalPrice)
    let chosenPrice = Double(round(1000*priceAsDouble!)/1000)
    let calculation = String(Double(textInput.text!)! / chosenPrice)
    let calcAsDouble = Double(calculation)
    let calcFinal = Double(round(1000*calcAsDouble!)/1000)
    if textInput.text != nil
    {
        textLabel.text = "\(calcFinal) \(names[choice])"
    }

}
//show/hide the converter
var showhide: Bool = false
@IBAction func showConverter(_ sender: Any) {
    if (showhide) {

        showhide = false
        self.tiOut(); self.tlOut(); self.cbOut()


    } else {

        showhide = true
        self.tlIn(); self.tiIn(); self.cbIn()

    }
}

//functions for showing and hiding each converter Item
func cbIn() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.convertButton.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    },
                   completion: nil
    )
}

func tiIn() {
    self.textInput.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.textInput.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    },
                   completion: nil
    )
}


func cbOut() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.convertButton.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    },
                   completion: nil
    )
}

func tiOut() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.textInput.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    },
                   completion: nil
    )
}

func tlIn() {
    self.textLabel.isHidden = false
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.textLabel.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    },
                   completion: nil
    )

}

func tlOut() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.textLabel.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    },
                   completion: nil
    )
}

//Convert button calls convert function
@IBAction func convertButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.convert()
}

//page load animation, var appeared making sure animation only occurs once

func mainAnimations() {
    if appeared == false {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            self.currencyIcon.center.y += self.view.bounds.height
        },
                       completion: nil
        )

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [],
                       animations: {
                        self.currencyPrice.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
        },
                       completion: nil
        )

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.4, options: [],
                       animations: {
                        self.labelName.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
        },
                       completion: nil
        )

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 2.0, options: [], animations: {

            self.euroPrice.alpha = 0.5
            self.usdPrice.alpha = 0.5
        })

        appeared = true

    } else {

    }
}

func backupAnimations() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.currencyIcon.center.y += self.view.bounds.height
    },
                   completion: nil
    )

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.currencyPrice.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    },
                   completion: nil
    )

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.4, options: [],
                   animations: {
                    self.labelName.center.x -= self.view.bounds.width
    },
                   completion: nil
    )
}

var appeared: Bool = false
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.mainAnimations()

}



//Dismiss Keyboard when Tap
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>,
                           with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

//get permCoin from user defaults and generate number, so now on always will be this coin.
func getPermCoinNumber() {

    let permString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "temp2")!
    let permNumber = names.firstIndex(of: permString)

    choice = permNumber!

    print("Debugging")
    print(names.debugDescription)
    print(permString.debugDescription)
    print(permNumber.debugDescription)
    print("Debugging end")
}

func animateContainerOut() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.searchView.center.y += self.view.bounds.height
    },
                   completion: nil
    )
}
func hideContainerView(){

    animateContainerOut()
   appeared = false
    self.viewDidLoad()
    self.viewDidAppear(true)
    backupAnimations()
    NewPageSearch.tempCase = ""
    NewPageSearch.tempController = nil

}

//displays chosen currency
func chooseCurrency() {
    let chosenName = names[choice]
    labelName.text = chosenName

}

//displays chosen price
func choosePrice() {

    let usdsPrice = usd[choice]
    let usdDoule = Double(usdsPrice)
    let usdFinal = Double(round(1000*usdDoule!)/1000)

    let eurosPrice = euros[choice]
    let euroDouble = Double(eurosPrice)
    let euroFinal = Double(round(1000*euroDouble!)/1000)

    let originalPrice = prices[choice]
    let priceAsDouble = Double(originalPrice)
    let chosenPrice = Double(round(1000*priceAsDouble!)/1000)

    currencyPrice.text = "£\(chosenPrice)"
    euroPrice.text = "€\(euroFinal)"
    usdPrice.text = "$\(usdFinal)"

}

func chooseImage() {
    //displays chosen image
    let chosenImage = images[choice]

    let remoteImageUrl = URL(string: chosenImage)

    Alamofire.request(remoteImageUrl!).responseData { (response) in
        if response.error == nil {
            print(response.result)

            if let data = response.data {
                self.currencyIcon.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   t2ViewController = self

    //choose random Background
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor( patternImage: UIImage(named: "\(backgroundArray[b])")!).withAlphaComponent(0.5)

    //Setup
    self.convertButton.center.x  += view.bounds.width
    self.textInput.center.x -= view.bounds.width
    self.textLabel.center.x -= view.bounds.width

    currencyIcon.center.y  -= view.bounds.height
    currencyPrice.center.x -= view.bounds.width
    labelName.center.x += view.bounds.width


    self.euroPrice.alpha = 0.0
    self.usdPrice.alpha = 0.0

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let urlString = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins?per_page=300"

    if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        if let data = try? String(contentsOf: url) {
            let json = JSON(parseJSON: data)


            parse(json: json)


        }

    }
}

//Parsing Coin API
func parse(json: JSON) {
    for result in json[].arrayValue {
        let name = result["name"].stringValue
        let price = result["market_data"]["current_price"]["gbp"].stringValue
        let euro = result["market_data"]["current_price"]["eur"].stringValue
        let usds = result["market_data"]["current_price"]["usd"].stringValue
        let image = result["image"]["small"].stringValue
        usd.append(usds)
        euros.append(euro)
        names.append(name)
        prices.append(price)
        images.append(image)
        }
    if (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "temp2") as? String) == nil {
        //show firstsearch

        NewPageSearch.tempCase = "temp2"
        NewPageSearch.tempController = t2ViewController
        appeared = true
        self.searchView.isHidden = false
        print("T2VCDebug")
        print(NewPageSearch.tempCase)
        print(NewPageSearch.tempController)
    } else {
        //show main screen
        appeared = false
        self.searchView.isHidden = true
        self.getPermCoinNumber()
        self.chooseCurrency()
        self.choosePrice()
        self.chooseImage()
        NewPageSearch.tempCase = ""
        NewPageSearch.tempController = nil
    }



}



}
```

Comment: Look at separation of concerns. View controllers shouldn't be concerned with storing data; Use a data model class or struct for that.  The view controller will need a reference to the instance of the data model it is concerned with.  Similarly with parsing JSON; View controllers aren't concerned with that.  A network operation object should retrieve data and produce a data model instance

Comment: Okay thank you, I will start doing some more research into that, is this a good place to start? https://medium.com/@johnsundell/separation-of-concerns-using-protocols-in-swift-319614c1880e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common make a Network and Utility classes in the app for handling Data & UI respectively like

```
class Utility {

   static let shared = Utility()

   func animate(view:UIView) { // in your case you have same duration you can send only + or - or create 2 functions for each

  }
}
```

//

```
class Network {

   static let shared = Network()

   func getData(completion:@escaping(_arr:[Type])->()) { // in your case you have same duration you can send only + or - or create 2 functions for each
     /// alamofire / urlsession request
     /// after finish completion(arr) 
  }
}
```

//

you can also have this sort of sharing

```
struct API {

   static let developmentUrlStr = "https://////"

   static let distributionUrlStr = "https://////"
}
```

//

```
Network.shared.getData { (arr) in 

   // get the array here 
}
```

Comment: So for example, would I make a new swift file i.e. CoinAPI.swift, create the Network class and in the getData function put my urlRequest and parse functions and keep the array variables in there also, so that I can access them from the template ViewController, how would I access it from there, would I Import Network,  or am I missing something? thanks

Comment: Network is a class not a framework to import , classes can be seen anywhere , see edit to call the function , sure you can send parameter as you want to make less functions as much as possible by combining shared cases in 1 function

Comment: Okay, It works well for the API. Lastly, for the animations how would I manage that, as the @IBOutlets are specific to the ViewController and I'm not sure how I would go about having all my animation functions inside a Utility class for each different ViewController, perhaps it is better to keep them in the ViewController because they are specific to that class? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: send the label as a parameter to the animate function declared in Utility

Comment: `Utility` is the worst name for a class. In a language with extensions you don't need static methods on a random class, it's better to add the methods to the correct types.